# This webpage is not available, The connection to xxx.domain.pl was interrupted, only first pageload

Tags: dns, html, bluehost

I'm experiencing odd error while trying to load my web page in browser. When I haven't opened it for some period of time and then try to open it just by typing address in browser and clicking enter: 
1) The page doesn't load - browser message that it is not available, connection to .... was interrupted 
  (in Opera there is also info about proxy, network... i can paste it later when error repeat again)
2) after refreshing, loading page again it works ok (without any problem) 
   My web page address is crib.pl and subdomains niemiecki.crib.pl, hiszpanski.crib.pl 
   it is important to note that when i try first time load for example niemiecki.crib.pl then it doesn't open but next opening hiszpanski.crib.pl will open normaly also.

Some additional info:
- hosting is in bluehost (Utha, USA)
- I'm trying to access this from (Poland, Europe)
- website is on drupal 
- it works for more than 4 years without problem on this server 
- it works even week ago without a problem and it doesn't work since 31 december 2014 
- bluehost support doesn't have any idea, they say it works perfectly 1-to-1 cases (no problem) 
  (If you can check it and type your country and whether yes/no you are expiriencing similar problem) 
- I haven't modified anything on the web page (problem just happens without my interaction)
- Google crawlers seems to have some problems with accessing robots.txt (sth like that) file
- domain is hosted by company in Poland (crib.pl) and this domain is set using external DNS to bluehost.com servers

Any help save my life, I'm experiencing about 50% drop in earnings since this problem!

Opera message: 
"
This webpage is not available

The connection to crib.pl was interrupted.
Check your internet connection.
Check any cables and reboot any routers, modems, or other network devices you may be using.
Allow Opera to access the network in your firewall or antivirus settings.
If it is already listed as a program allowed to access the network, try removing it from the list and adding it again.
If you use a proxy server...
Check your proxy settings or contact your network administrator to make sure the proxy server is working. If you don't believe you should be using a proxy server: Go to Applications > System Preferences > Network > Advanced > Proxies and deselect any proxies that have been selected.
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as I thought before the problem was with bluehost box. 
Now seems that the problem has been fixed. Here's what I have done: 
1) I upgraded bluehost account (standard shared to pro shared) 
   I do this because want to change IP address and bluehost box without changing crib.pl 
   domain external DNS servers configurations (it is set to bluehost) 
   I also would like to have automatic migration, because haven't too much time now.
2) After upgrade I get new IP address and new bluehost box but it also didn't work correctly
3) So I switch on dedicated IP option and after that about 6 hours later when dedicated IP was propageted properly website seems to work again correctly  (one problem it cost me about 120$ for next year and shortening my plan for 1 year then previously)
4) the most frustrating issue was bluehost technical support approach which wasn't eager to help me in any why even though the problem was in their server configuration not my code !

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely something wrong with the Bluehost box (i.e. the server behind the IP address 66.147.244.170). From Australia at 2015-Jan-05 12:19:36 UTC, I was able to reproduce a "Connection reset by peer" error just using curl, which corresponds to the browser message "connection to .. was interrupted".

Other times, it just hangs while trying to establish a connection.

In addition, other servers on the same subnet also owned by Bluehost appear to be working fine.

For example:

```
$ telnet 66.147.244.22 80
Trying 66.147.244.22...
Connected to 66-147-244-22.unifiedlayer.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> q
Connection closed.
```

This tells me that it is not a routing problem on the public Internet either.

Also, after a while I tried again it succeeded in opening a connection. So, you're right that the problem is intermittent.

In other words, I think the issue lies with this particular Bluehost box. It could be one of the following causes:

- OS is out of file descriptors
- Apache or whatever mail server is too slow to service requests and therefore has maxed out its [listen backlog](http://www.linuxjournal.com/files/linuxjournal.com/linuxjournal/articles/023/2333/2333s2.html)
- other server resource limits (perhaps memory) or network equipment issue localized to the hosting environment

Best to check with Bluehost again. My guess is that one of the [other tenants sharing that server](http://www.tcpiputils.com/browse/ip-address/66.147.244.170) is getting heavily loaded periodically.